# Android layout_weight Not Working

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a fragment with 5 buttons in it. When its on a larger screen like a tablet I use a fragment that places all 5 buttons at the top. I set all their layout_width to 1 but the buttons do not spread evenly across the screen like is expected.

EXPECTED
[  all ][  my  ][buttons][  go  ][  here ]

WHAT I GET
b1    b2   b3   b4  b5      b3 and b5 are just one button... just showing it breaks one word
[all][my][but ][go][her]    and puts it one line down.
         [tons]    [e  ]

I have been playing with it and trying different things but I cant get it to change. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/xlarge_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tip_btn"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="@string/tip_button"
    android:onClick="tipButton">
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/preference"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="@string/settings"
    android:onClick="showPreferences">
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rate_btn"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="@string/rate_button"
    android:onClick="rateButton">
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/feedback_btn"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="@string/feedback_button"
    android:onClick="feedbackButton">
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="@string/exit_button"
    android:onClick="cancelButton">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Provide your XML layout to see the error.

Comment: sorry i was gonna do that but forgot. here it is. it doesnt space the buttons evenly they are scrunched together. they all have one word in them and on 2 the one word is split into 2 lines.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Short answer: set the layout_width of the buttons to 0. The layout_weight is used to determine how to spread the left-over space between the elements in a layout. Therefore, if you don't set the width to zero, the size of the content of the buttons will affect how big they are.

Here are two good blog posts explaining how weights work:

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/297
http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/312

Comment: How is this the accepted answer when the OP's XML already sets width of all buttons to zero?

Comment: Because there was no XML in the question when it was answered.

Comment: Pro tip to seed confusion on SO: apply solution from answer to your question.

Answer (score 8):

Since You are using layout_weight, You should give 0dp for layout_width. It should work.

Comment: And layout_height should set to 0dp